# How to put a logo above the title on a baposter?

Tags: spacing, baposter

I am making a poster with the [`baposter` class](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/).

For template reasons, I would like to insert a logo *above* the title and authors, meaning they should be lowered and the boxes as well.

How can I achieve this? I tried following things without success.

- Adding `headerheight=...` in the arguments of `\begin{poster}`: adds space should there be more authors, but the title itself stays at the same vertical position.
- Adding positive/negative `vspace`s: does not do what I expected.

MWE (adapted from the ECCS2011 tutorial that comes with `baposter`):

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{relsize}        % For \smaller

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40}
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{186,215,230}
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{186,215,230}

\begin{document}

\background{
}

\begin{poster}{
    grid=false, 
    borderColor=bordercol,
    headerColorOne=headercol1,
    headerColorTwo=headercol2,
    headerFontColor=headerfontcol,
    boxColorOne=boxcolor,
    headershape=roundedright,
    headerfont=\Large\sf\bf,
    textborder=rectangle,
    background=user,
    headerborder=open,
    boxshade=plain
}
%%% Eye Cacther %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
}
%%% Title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\sf\bf
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{pix/elte_logo}\\
    Can I lower this title?
}
%%% Authors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
    \vspace{1em} Pr. Oblematic\\
    {\smaller Affiliation \\ Long affiliation \\ Very long affiliation}
}
%%% Logo %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
}

\headerbox{Problem}{name=problem1,column=0,row=0}{
}

\headerbox{Solution}{name=solution1,column=0,below=problem1,above=bottom}{
}

\headerbox{Problem}{name=problem2,span=2,column=1,row=0}{
}

\headerbox{Solution}{name=solution2,span=2,column=1,below=problem2,above=bottom}{
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: If you are open for alternatives, I would use the tcolorbox package for a poster design like this

Comment: Add `headerheight=0.15\textheight,` to specify the height of the header area and then add some extra space in the line break like this: `\includegraphics[height=2cm]{pix/elte_logo}\\[12pt]`. Otherwise, use the `poster` library from `tcolorbox`.